# Keyboard focus vs logical focus in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5, focus

What is the difference by Keyboard focus and logical focus in WPF? and how WPF focus is different from the focus in winform ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

see [Focus Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa969768(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Keyboard focus refers to the element that is currently receiving
>   keyboard input. There can be only one element on the whole desktop
>   that has keyboard focus. In WPF, the element that has keyboard focus
>   will have IsKeyboardFocused set to true. The static property
>   FocusedElement on the Keyboard class gets the element that currently
>   has keyboard focus.
>
> Logical focus refers to the FocusManager.FocusedElement in a focus
>   scope. A focus scope is an element that keeps track of the
>   FocusedElement within its scope. When keyboard focus leaves a focus
>   scope, the focused element will lose keyboard focus but will retain
>   logical focus. When keyboard focus returns to the focus scope, the
>   focused element will obtain keyboard focus. This allows for keyboard
>   focus to be changed between multiple focus scopes but ensures that the
>   focused element in the focus scope regains keyboard focus when focus
>   returns to the focus scope.

Comment: So, when to use logical focus?

Comment: What you mean when to use?

Comment: When should use it.

Comment: The idea is that when no focus on window, there is still logical focus... left on the last element that had a focus

Comment: What's the use?

Answer (score 10):

I found a good series of blog posts on WPF focus.

1. [Part1ItsBasicallyFocus](https://markjulmar.github.io/dotnet/2008/09/02/part-1-its-basically-focus.html)
2. [Part2ChangingWPFFocusInCode](https://markjulmar.github.io/wpf/2008/09/04/part-2-changing-wpf-focus-in-code.html)
3. [Part3ShiftingFocusToTheFirstAvailableElementInWPF](https://markjulmar.github.io/wpf/2008/09/12/part-3-shifting-focus-to-the-first-available-element-in-wpf.html)

They are all good to read, but the 1st part specifically deals with logical vs keyboard focus.  The 3rd part shows a good way to set focus to a UI element in a UserControl.

Comment: These articles have moved and can currently be found at:
http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=52
http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=51
http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=50

Comment: Link-only answers are susceptible to link-rot.

Comment: Links all broken.

Comment: The author must have removed those posts.

Comment: I fixed the links.