# Why is wpf element not returning true for IsFocused Property

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a WPF application. In the code behind I am calling a method when an element loses focus as shown below.

```
private void expander_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
    if(NMButton.IsFocused)
    {
        expander.IsExpanded = false;
    }
}
```

When the `focusedControl` object gets set, it is set to `NMButton`. However, in the next line of code `NMButton.IsFocused` returns `false`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1320824/5147720, maybe you are in a different focus scope.

Comment: If I check NMButton.IsKeyboardFocused it returns true. Kinda confusing. I thought that FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) returned the item that has logical focus. Oh well. This will work. Thanks man.